# How to tell if loaded page is true XML-processed XHTML or not, using devtools or JavaScript snippet

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xhtml, detection

Inspecting Firefox system page that is displayed when connection to remote server fails  shows clear signs it is a true `application/xhtml+xml` page:

[image: Developer Tools - Problem loading page - http://localhost:4200 inspecting DOM tree. All elements in expanded head (meta, link) have closing tags, what would not show in regular HTML]

There is explicit `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, all elements, even void ones, have closing tags, so it most probably is processed as XML. This brings the question:

**What would be the easiest way for script loaded in such page or for Developer Tools command to tell XML processed page apart from regular HTML?**

Checking `document.documentElement.namespaceURI` property gives `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in both cases.

- What DOM property or method could serve as sign page is XML?
- Or is some more complex detection procedure necessary (like doing some DOM/XSLT/entities stuff that works exclusively in XML) to be sure?

---

Source of the depicted system page is presumably `view-source:chrome://global/content/aboutNetError.xhtml` but, it does not work when displayed directly.

Comment: What does `document.contentType` show? `application/xhtml+xml` or `text/html`?

Comment: You could use the methods described in this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regex-to-match-open-html-tags-except-self-contained-xhtml-tags/ , and check for the /html/head/link elements. In xhtml they should be self closed, but in html not

Comment: @MartinHonnen `document.contentType` indeed shows the mimetype of interest (`"application/xhtml+xml"` for the page in question). Nice, this is the answer I was after, thanks. (Would you mind repeating it as real answer so I can accept it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`document.contentType`** should give you `"application/xhtml+xml"` for XML parsed XHTML documents and `"text/html"` for HTML(5) parsed HTML documents.

Specs: [WHATWG:contentType](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-contenttype), docs: [MDN: Document: contentType property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/contentType).

Demo:

```html
This document's <code>contentType</code>:<br/>
<script>document.body.append(document.contentType)</script>

<hr>

<p>Iframe with minimal XHTML and same content:</p>

<iframe src='data:application/xhtml+xml,
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body>
  This document%27s <code>contentType</code>:<br/>
  <script>document.body.append(document.contentType) </script>
  </body></html>
'></iframe>
```